# TypeError: Image constructor: 'new' is required

Tags: image, import, next.js, nextjs-image

i'm trying to use the next js Image component but i got this error, i just made this simple page to test the image component with prismic cms, i get this error even when i use the img html tag

```js
import Image from "next/image";

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Image className="" src="../public/vercel.svg" layout="fill" />
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

TypeError: Image constructor: 'new' is required

Comment: Looking at this blog seems like you might have missed the `import` https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-fix-constructor-requires-new-operator/. Can you check again and if not then maybe show where youare using Test

Comment: That error is not reproducible with the code you provided. However, you might get an error because of the `src` value you're using - you should use `src="/vercel.svg"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I didn't import the image component inside one of the components in my project, so this is why I got this error even in a very simple and separated component. Thanks for the comments!